# mod_rewrite regex rule with encoded new lines (%0A)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, urlencode

I'm having some problems with a mod_rewrite rule not matching, when I think it should.

The rule is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)\.(json|xml|csv|txt|printr|basictxt)$ api/endpoint.php?api_request=$1&api_response_type=$2 [QSA]
```

And an example url is:

```
http://ourdomain.tld/api/aaaaa/bbbb/cccc%0Adddd.json
```

This rule works fine as long as you don't have `$0A` in the url (as far as I can tell).

I realise that `.` means anything other than a new line and have tried rules like the following to get around either new lines or percentage symbols as I'm not sure quite how it is formatted at the time that mod_rewrite sees it, but none have worked:

```
RewriteRule ^api/([.\s]*)\.(json|xml|csv|txt|printr|basictxt)$ api/endpoint.php?api_request=$1&api_response_type=$2 [QSA]


RewriteRule ^api/([.\%]*)\.(json|xml|csv|txt|printr|basictxt)$ api/endpoint.php?api_request=$1&api_response_type=$2 [QSA]


RewriteRule ^api/([.%]*)\.(json|xml|csv|txt|printr|basictxt)$ api/endpoint.php?api_request=$1&api_response_type=$2 [QSA]
```

Strangely even the following fails on all urls, even those without `%` symbols:

```
RewriteRule ^api/([.]*)\.(json|xml|csv|txt|printr|basictxt)$ api/endpoint.php?api_request=$1&api_response_type=$2 [QSA]
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could shed some light on this for me as I cannot really go changing how the API works (IE I cannot make it base64 encoded, etc) and need to get a value to it with a new line in it.

I've tested it at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and their tool thinks it should work!

**EDIT:**

**We had a solution for the URL above but it didn't work with an example like:**

```
/api/something/sent+40.06K+bytes++received+7.83M+bytes++542.70K+bytes%2Fsec%0Atotal+size+is+19.83G++speedup+is+2520.16+%28Completed+in+14+seconds%29.json
```

Thanks.

Comment: mod_rewrite is iffy with newlines (and other encoded special characters, like slashes). A way to match them would be to use the `\x` escape sequence: `\x0A` is the hex representation of newline. A commonly seen construct is `[\x00-\xff]`, quite literally "any byte", you may try working with that, like `RewriteRule api/([\x00-\xff])*?\.(json|xml|csv|txt|printr|basictxt)$` Note the lazy star. I can't test it now, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: @SáT, thanks. I've tried that but no luck again! There must be a way to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

> ....and need to get a value to it with a **newline** in it.

You're missing the caret `^` considered the negation operator inside of your character class `[^.]`

```
RewriteRule ^api/([^.]*)\.(json|xml|csv|txt|printr|basictxt)$ api/endpoint.php?api_request=$1&api_response_type=$2 [QSA]
```

See [`regex101`](http://regex101.com/r/tL8qI3) demo

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does seem to work, but I'm a little confused. Doesn't the caret mean any character except those in the group. I.e. `[A-Z]` would match any uppercase letter and `[^A-Z]` anything but an uppercase letter? So surely `[^.]` means only match new lines (or other things not matched by just `.` on its own?) Anyway, your answer seems to have done the trick, so thank you.

Comment: Actually here it's saying match everything up until a dot `.` then match the dot `\.` It negation for `"anything but a dot"`.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried a few more genuine values that would be sent to the API and some do contain dots (so failed) and then I saw your edit with `[\S\s]` which I've tried on the next string, but it is not working. regex101 think it should though http://regex101.com/r/uO0kA6 Can you help?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I can use regex101. The regex101 link that I gave you says that the regular expression matches the input, but in my .haccess file it is not matching. regex101 is using the PCRE (PHP) flavour of regex and clearly mode_rewrite is using something else.

Comment: Try removing the `^` anchor here. `RewriteRule api/(.*)\.(json|xml|csv|txt|printr|basictxt)$ ...`

Comment: If I remove the `^` then I'm back at what I started with originally, which didn't work.